# how to get the extracted feature vector from transfer learning models python?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a classification model with ResNet50. I know, CNN or transfer learning models extract the features themselves. How can I get the extracted feature vector from the image dataset in python?

Code Snippet of model training:

```
base_model = ResNet152V2(
    input_shape = (height, width, 3),
    include_top=False,
    weights='imagenet'
)
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPool2D, BatchNormalization, GlobalAveragePooling2D

top_model = base_model.output
top_model = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(top_model)


top_model = Dense(1072, activation='relu')(top_model)
top_model = Dropout(0.6)(top_model)  
top_model = Dense(256, activation='relu')(top_model)
top_model = Dropout(0.6)(top_model)


prediction = Dense(len(categories), activation='softmax')(top_model)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=prediction)

for layer in model.layers:
  layer_trainable=False
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
model.compile(
  optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.00001),
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  metrics=['accuracy']
)
import keras
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
es_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)


datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range= 30,
                             width_shift_range=0.2,
                             height_shift_range=0.2, 
                             shear_range=0.2,
                             zoom_range=0.3,
                             horizontal_flip=True
                             )

resnet152v2 = model.fit(datagen.flow(X_train, y_train),
                        validation_data = (X_val, y_val),
                        epochs = 100,
                        callbacks=[es_callback]
                        )
```

I followed a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50756554/13359498).

Code snippet of extracting features from the trained model:

```
extract = Model(model.inputs, model.layers[-3].output) #top_model = Dropout(0.6)(top_model)
features = extract.predict(X_test)
```

The shape of X_test is `(120, 224, 224, 3)`

Comment: Extract feature vector from where? The code you have given is for model training. Extracting feature vector (of the dense layers at the end) is done by removing the softmax dense layer and getting the output from the penultimate dense. If you want the outputs from the CNN layers, you would have to do the same.

Comment: I want to print or see the shape of the feature vector. but I don't know how to proceed. My confusion is, I am building the model first then I am training the model. If i write a print line right after the last dense layer, it won't work because my model is not trained yet.

Comment: You are correct. You must first train the model, then remove the last dense layer, then run the model (inference) to receive the result of the feature vector. I will post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have trained your model, you can save it (or just directly use it in the same file) then cut off the top layer.

```
model = load_model("xxx.h5")   #Or use model directly

#Use functional model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
featuresModel = Model(inputs=model.input,outputs=model.layers[-3].output)   #Get rids of dropout too

#Inference directly
featureVector = featuresModel.predict(yourBatchData, batch_size=yourBatchLength)
```

If inferenced in batches, you would need to separate the output results to see the result for each input in the batch.

Comment: I'm getting an  `InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313818/tensorflow-dst-tensor-is-not-initialized